# Read a file, but hint the kernel not to cache its contents?

Tags: linux, caching, linux-kernel, posix, system-calls

I noticed I'm getting major problems with system's responsiveness (desktop GUI) after performing a command like this:

`cat file_larger_than_ram.bin | ./simple-process`

My theory is that this causes the Linux kernel to discard the cache of files it held so far in the unused part of RAM. At the same time, the processes need to access the data they work on, so after performing the command above, they have to load their files again. Given that I'm only going to use `file_larger_than_ram.bin` once, is there a way to hint kernel not to cache the file? I heard that I could use `fadvise` for that, but I'm not sure given what `fadvise64(2)` says:

> POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED attempts to free cached pages associated with the specified region.  This is useful, for example, while
>   streaming large files.  A program may periodically request the kernel
>   to free cached data that has already been used, so that more useful
>   cached pages are not discarded instead.

Would applying `fdadvise (input_desc, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED);` actually behave as I expect and solve the problem here?

Comment: Any problems with checking it? From the description it seems that it should work

Comment: Testing all the alternatives would take a lot of time, so I figured I'd ask in case somebody already knows the answer. It looks like "dd" could be useful here - I proposed addition to `cat`: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2015-10/msg00111.html and found that it was already rejected once.

Comment: Have you seen this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36907/drop-a-specific-file-from-the-linux-filesystem-cache ?

Comment: @AlexHoppus: nope, but it's amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Feel invited to reference this answer and summarize it in an answer to this question and I'll be happy to upvote & accept it.

Answer (score 5):

> Given that I'm only going to use file_larger_than_ram.bin once, is there a way to hint kernel not to cache the file?

To my knowledge, that is possible with the `O_DIRECT` flag to the `open` syscall. But the flag comes with additional limitations (e.g. file offset and user-space memory buffer alignment) which might cause problems. They didn't cause problems to me in the tests, but the documentation says that the behavior is device/file system specific. Thus I changed my code to use the `fadvise()`.

(Additionally, I have observed some performance irregularities (the `read()`/`write()` were too fast) which suggested that even with `O_DIRECT` some data sometimes were getting cached. YMMV.)

> I heard that I could use fadvise for that, but I'm not sure [...]

It wasn't clear to me either, so I have checked the kernel source code. The effect of `fadvise()` call with `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` is to remove the corresponding data from the cache. I haven't seen anything to suggest that the flag is *sticky* and applies to all of the file operations. (Which was why I have checked the source code: I know that Linux performs I/O *always* through the cache, with the `O_DIRECT` being the alternative. The sticky `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` didn't fit into the paradigm.)

In other words, to free the cache during reading you need:

- keep the track of the file offset before the `read()`
- after the `read()`, call `fadvise(POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)` on the range of data which you have just read.
- for best results, you have to read the data in page-aligned blocks. The I/O cache is page based, and the `fadvise()` maps the specified data range into the list of pages. The misalignment would cause extra `read()`s (and harm performance) but otherwise is harmless.

For writing it is little bit more complicated: I have observed that `fadvise(POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)` has no effect if called right after the `write()`. One has to call `fsync()`/`fdatasync()` to force data being written, thus unpinning the cache entries, and only then call the `fadvise(POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)` to free them.

P.S. As far as I have understood the kernel code, the trick with `dd` linked to by @AlexHoppus should work. For example `cat file; dd if=file of=/dev/null iflag=nocache` - the `cat` call would put the file into cache, `dd` would read it from cache, and then discard it from cache. The `fadvise(POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)` operates on the global cache, and thus it is irrelevant who/when read the data, it would discard them anyway.